# How to enable HDFS caching on Amazon EMR?

Tags: emr, hdf

What's the easiest way to enable [HDFS Caching](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/CentralizedCacheManagement.html) on EMR ?

More specifically, how to set `dfs.datanode.max.locked.memory` and increase the "maximum size that may be locked into memory" (`ulimit -l`) on all nodes ?

The following code seems to work fine for `dfs.datanode.max.locked.memory` and I could probably write a custom bootstrap to update `/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-daemon.sh` and call `ulimit`. Is there any better or faster way ?

```
elastic-mapreduce --create \
    --alive \
    --plain-output \
    --visible-to-all \
    --ami-version  3.1.0 \
    -a $access_id \
    -p $private_key \
    --name "test" \
    --master-instance-type m3.xlarge \
    --instance-group master --instance-type m3.xlarge  --instance-count 1 \
    --instance-group core --instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 10 \
    --pig-interactive \
    --log-uri s3://foo/bar/logs/ \
    --bootstrap-action s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop \
    --args "--hdfs-key-value,dfs.datanode.max.locked.memory=2000000000" \
```